# Query documents using Pymongo Datetime

Tags: mongodb-query, pymongo

when I run the below query in MongoDB Compass,  I am able to get the documents what I want:

```
{"save_date" : { "$gte" : new Date("2019-02-25T08:01:59"),"$lte":new Date("2019-02-25T08:02:59")}}
```

But when I use pymongo, I am getting 0 documents, I have been using these in below 2 versions and none of them are giving me the data that I want, Any idea what is missing?.

```
    connection = MongoDbClient("With all the connection parameters")

    start = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S')
    end = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_date, '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S')

    connection.database.collection.find({ "save_date": {"$gte" : start, "$lte": end}}).count()
```

returned 0 documents

The below version returned 0 document as well

```
   connection.database.collection.find({ "save_date": {"$gte" : datetime.datetime(2019,2,25,8,1,59), "$lte": datetime.datetime(2019,2,25,8,2,59)}}).count()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess found the issue. Looks like I was passing all the dates as local data and time where there was no document for that date range, Hence 0 documents returned. Now I have converted my local date to UTC date and before passing to pymongo worked great and got my documents.

```
 local_start="2019-02-25 08:01:59"
 start = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", 
        time.gmtime(time.mktime(time.strptime(local_start, 
                            "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))))
```

Comment: Have a look on `datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 25, 8, 1, 59)`, `datetime.datetime.now()`, `datetime.datetime.utcnow()` and other functions from this module. It will be easier to use them instead of doing lots of convertions like `strftime`

Comment: Glad to help you